# Не показывает flex по изменению если @media (max-width: 997px)

Tags: html, css, scss, flexbox

Наверно что-то зависит от браузеров?

```
.articles-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: stretch;
    .item {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        align-self: flex-start;
        flex: 1 0 30%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {    
    .item {
        flex: 1 0 48%;
    }
}
```

Comment: flex-direction: row; - это используется по-умолчанию и указывать его нету смысла, flex-wrap: wrap; - это не нужно, если вы не используете inline, align-content: stretch; - не имеет смысла, так как используется justify-content

Answer (score 0):

```
.articles-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: stretch;
        .item {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            align-self: flex-start;
            flex: 1 0 30%;
        }
}

@media screen and(max-width: 997px) { 
  .articles-list {
    .item {
        flex: 1 0 48%;
    }
  }
}
```

или так

```
 .articles-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: stretch;
        .item {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            align-self: flex-start;
            flex: 1 0 30%;

          @media screen and(max-width: 997px) {   
              & {
                  flex: 1 0 48%;
              }
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: не работает. у меня chrome google 29.0

Comment: с префиксами пробовали использовать флекс? Возможно и впрямь через чур старая версия браузера.

`display: box; is a version of 2009.
display: flexbox; is a version of 2011.
display: flex; is the actual version.`

Comment: я так раньше сделал префикс. результат ничего не изменилось

Comment: решил проблему, необходимо добавить !important

Comment: не советую решать проблемы через !important

Comment: если !important решает проблмеу, значит что-то перебивает стили! Странно что мое пример не работает.

Comment: кто то сможет объяснить корректно в чем сути, от чего зависит !ipmortant?

Comment: !important - это запрет браузеру использовать пользовательские настройки.

Comment: @Юрий, запрет? Ну не стоит так!) !important позволяет повысить приоритет стиля и не более, и ничего он не запрещает, просто перебивает даже инлайновые стили.

Comment: повышение приоритета - это собственно и есть запрет. стиль заданный имеет прерогативу перед стилями браузера, но некоторые браузеры могут игнорировать данный запрос. К примеру, Opera - будет плевать если стоит данная квота у стиля в checkbox, а для Chrome  она будет действовать. Использование !important  - должно быть исключительностью в использовании, только там где браузеры насильно отказываются использовать данный стиль, flex не относиться к таким случаям

Comment: в данном случае у человека изначально неправильно сделан вывод в @media, у вас вывод верен, но если используется старая версия Chrome то нужен -webkit- префикс, если и он не работает, то надо апгредить своего мамонта.